# Photoswipe gallery with fluid transition

Tags: javascript, photoswipe

I'd like to have a fluid transition (horizontal floating) of the images in my [photoswipe gallery](http://photoswipe.com/documentation/getting-started.html)(see chapter "How to build an array of slides from a list of links"). If there are more pictures with different heights (or just different dimensions) so that the gallery needs more lines, you see the strict grid layout:

[image: strict grid design]

Is there any setting that allows me to change that static grid design in potoswipe?

Expected result:

[image: with fluid transition]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of searching I found [a solution](http://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/):

```
#photos {
   /* Prevent vertical gaps */
   line-height: 0;

   -webkit-column-count: 5;
   -webkit-column-gap:   0px;
   -moz-column-count:    5;
   -moz-column-gap:      0px;
   column-count:         5;
   column-gap:           0px;
}

#photos img {
  /* Just in case there are inline attributes */
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
}
```

The `#photos` id represents the `.my-simple-gallery` class of photoswipe.